# R function similar to Excel's match?

Tags: r, match

Good day
1) Is there a R function similar to Excel's match function?

2) I've made my own as below(lengthy..TT)
  Could anybody suggest things need to be improved? Or other way?

```
fmatch2<-function(ss1, ss2) { #ss1 correspond the first argument of Excel match function. ss2 for the second.
 fmatch<-function(ii,ss) { # return location in ss where ii match.
   if (length(which(ss==ii))>0 ) {
      rr<- min(which(ss==ii))
   } else {
      if (length(which(ss>ii))>0) 
      {rr<-min(which(ss>ii))-1 }
   }
 return(rr)
 }    
 rr<-list()
 n<-1
 for ( x  in ss1 ) { # apply fmatch to each member in ss1
     nn<-fmatch(x,ss2[1:n])
     rr<-rbind(rr,nn)
     n<-n+1
 }
 as.vector(unlist(rr[,1])) 
}
```

Usages of the function fmatch2 as below.
Mimicking Excel "=MATCH(H1,$I$1:1,1)".   Element name of the list below "ch, ci"   correspond to column H, Column I. The result is the list named cn.

```
x<-data.frame(cf=c(0,1,2,3,4,5),ch=c(0,0,3,6,6,6),ci=c(0,0,3,7,11,13))

y<-data.frame(cf=c(0,1,2,3,4,5),ch=c(0,0,3,6,6,6),ci=c(0,0,3,7,11,13),cn=fmatch2(x[[2]],x[[3]]))
```

Comment: does `?match` help? It only returns the first match. Otherwise, `?grep`

Comment: Are you trying to find the index of matches (i.e. what row have matches)?

Comment: Reading the doc of the Excel `match` (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a), it seems that it corresponds to actually two functions in R: it's `match` when the `match_type` is 0 and `findInterval` with the default value. OP, look at `?findInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse i am not entirely sure what you're trying to do, as i'd expect your `fmatch2` function to return `NA` for `ch==6` (because 6 is not present in ci), but i love doing things using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
result <- x %>%  # "%>%" means "and then"
          mutate(chInCi = match(ch, x$ci)) #adds a column named "chInCi" with the position in ci of the first match of the value in ch
```

result

```
 cf ch ci chInCi
1  0  0  0      1
2  1  0  0      1
3  2  3  3      3
4  3  6  7     NA
5  4  6 11     NA
6  5  6 13     NA
```